# How to prevent submitting form from outside the project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have written my code in one of my MVC application. Following example is my code for  tag.

e.g.

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/Home/savedata" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="[#DIV ID]" id="[FORM ID]" method="post">

// text-boxes for personal information.
// submit button

</form>
```

Above code is written in MVC using AJAX.Beginform.

I have copied  tag code in one html file and click on the button and it can save data which i have entered in html file. So how can i prevent this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use something called a "nonce" or "csrf token".
It's a string generated on the server along with the form.
When you submit the form just send the nonce along with your data and check its validity on the server before accepting the data into your system.